# AppEngine: ImportError: cannot import name docker

Tags: google-app-engine

I have recently updated my environment using gcloud component update. I am now having the following issue:

```
xxxxxx-MacBook-Air:~ poiuytrez$ dev_appserver.py .
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/dev_appserver.py", line 83, in <module>
    _run_file(__file__, globals())
  File "/usr/local/bin/dev_appserver.py", line 79, in _run_file
    execfile(_PATHS.script_file(script_name), globals_)
  File "/Applications/Miscelaneous/google-cloud-sdk/.install/.backup/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/devappserver2.py", line 36, in <module>
    from google.appengine.tools.devappserver2 import dispatcher
  File "/Applications/Miscelaneous/google-cloud-sdk/.install/.backup/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/dispatcher.py", line 29, in <module>
    from google.appengine.tools.devappserver2 import module
  File "/Applications/Miscelaneous/google-cloud-sdk/.install/.backup/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/module.py", line 75, in <module>
    from google.appengine.tools.devappserver2 import vm_runtime_factory
  File "/Applications/Miscelaneous/google-cloud-sdk/.install/.backup/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/vm_runtime_factory.py", line 25, in <module>
    from google.appengine.tools.devappserver2 import vm_runtime_proxy
  File "/Applications/Miscelaneous/google-cloud-sdk/.install/.backup/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/vm_runtime_proxy.py", line 29, in <module>
    from google.appengine.tools.devappserver2 import log_manager
  File "/Applications/Miscelaneous/google-cloud-sdk/.install/.backup/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/log_manager.py", line 34, in <module>
    from google.appengine.tools.docker import containers
  File "/Applications/Miscelaneous/google-cloud-sdk/.install/.backup/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/docker/containers.py", line 48, in <module>
    from docker import docker
ImportError: cannot import name docker
```

I am not sure what to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per [Google Cloud SDK - Release Notes for 0.9.68 (2015/07/08)](https://dl.google.com/dl/cloudsdk/release/RELEASE_NOTES)

> The standalone App Engine SDKs are no longer distributed through the Cloud SDK.
>
> App Engine functionality can still be used through the `gcloud preview app` command group.
>
> The gae-java, gae-python, gae-php, and gae-go components no longer exist in the component manager.
>
> If you need to use appcfg or dev_appserver directly, these are still
>   available in the App Engine SDK downloads that can be found here:
>   https://cloud.google.com/appengine/downloads

So your options are:

1. Run `gcloud preview app run app.yaml` from your project's home directory
2. Install the [Google App Engine SDK for python](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/downloads?hl=en_US#Google_App_Engine_SDK_for_Python) and use its bundled `dev_appserver`
3. Install [docker-py](https://github.com/docker/docker-py) to "fix" it.

More info in this [bug report](https://code.google.com/p/google-cloud-sdk/issues/detail?id=125)